# Adding Bouncycastle security provider to maven jar

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

When trying to compile my maven project that uses the bouncycastle security provider, I get this error: `java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC`
I am aware that the jar must be signed, so I have added this to the pom.xml to prevent an error with compilation:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>
                    package
                </phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Based on this ([bouncycastle provider can't find classes needed for algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908696/bouncycastle-provider-cant-find-classes-needed-for-algorithm)) I have added this: `Security.setProperty("java.policy", "unlimited");` and I have added the provider with this: `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`
in my public static void main.

Unfortunately, this didn't work. Do you have any suggestions of how to implement the thing shown in the post linked above without having to implement it for every JRE separately? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The bouncycastle jar is already signed by the bouncycastle key, not yours. The bouncycastle jar must be standalone.

Comment: So there is  no way to include it in an executable jar?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with the executable packer maven plugin (https://github.com/nthuemmel/executable-packer-maven-plugin) from this question: [How do I put all required JAR files in a library folder inside the final JAR file with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758594/how-do-i-put-all-required-jar-files-in-a-library-folder-inside-the-final-jar-fil/44226166#44226166)
It

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.ntcomputer</groupId>
            <artifactId>executable-packer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>mh.cryptomail.CryptoMail</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>pack-executable-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>mh.cryptomail.CryptoMail</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

It copies all jars to the resultant jar unmodified, but it takes a bit longer on startup (about 15s) since it has to register a custom classloader, but it works.